# string extract/match in between "_" but the value can have no space/space/or be numeric and have special characters (i.e. &)

Tags: r

I have a set of strings and possible examples are: AS-04_PS Fans (Interest) Sci-Fi Games Interest_IND, AS-08_5-694640-113017 & CRM_INDAS-08_5-694640-113017_IND.

I want to extract the sequence between the underscores.

I used the code:
`str_match(x,"_(\\w+?)_IND")[,2]`

I'm noticing this code works better if I get rid of the spaces and parenthesis. Any way for me to properly extract without messing with the data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
x <- "AS-04_PS Fans (Interest) Sci-Fi Games Interest_IND, AS-08_5-694640-113017 & CRM_INDAS-08_5-694640-113017_IND"
str_split(x, "_IND")

# [[1]]
# [1] "AS-04_PS Fans (Interest) Sci-Fi Games Interest" ", AS-08_5-694640-113017 & CRM"                  "AS-08_5-694640-113017"                         
# [4] ""
```